# Disable collapse for link in a data-toggle element

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a collapsing panel body, like this ([the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/langner/dLqK6/), which now has the fixed code):

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">
            <a href="#">1) collapsing link</a>
            <a href="#">2) not collapsing link</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">Anim pariatur cliche ...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The data-toggle is set on the panel title, because I want a click anywhere on it to open the other panel. Except the second link. My goal is to disable the collapsing behavior for the second link. What is the best/simplest way to achieve that?

**Important**: I do not want to set the data-toggle on the first link only. I want a click anywhere on the panel to trigger the even, except on the second link.

Comment: Why don't set `data-toggle="collapse"` to the link that you want to fire the event?

Comment: @JorgeGarcía because it doesn't work then

Comment: @Adjit It will still work, but not the way I want.

Comment: @Karol so I know you set a tag as Javascript but would a JQuery answer satisfy?

Comment: @Adjit Of course! I have jquery loaded along with bootstrap already.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to add a class for those elements that you don't want to fire the collapse event and then stop the event propagation via javascript. So... here is the correct answer.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">
            <a href="#">1) collapsing link</a>
            <a href="#" class="no-collapsable">2) not collapsing link</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">Anim pariatur cliche ...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Stop the event propagation like this:

```
$('.no-collapsable').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Well, it is not what I want. I clearly said I want the collapse to be triggered when the panel is clicked, anywhere. Except the second link.

Comment: gotcha, so, let me check how we can do that.

Comment: @Karol I updated my answer... let me know if this is that you want.

Comment: @JorgeGarcía so much years later, but with bootstrap 5 i face the same poblem and your solution is not working, cause while triggering the event listener where we then stop the propagation the collapsable item is already open. So the collapse opening event was already done/finished